# vector<list<int>> Inserting elements in Graph using Vector of List in C++

Tags: c++, graph, stl

Why i am asking this because I am using adj[v].push_back(w) to insert nodes in a graph.
For this to work I need to increase size of my vector, but I don't want that ,as I have only 4 nodes.
so adj[v] will always be the index but what if we have a graph with nodes as
9 __ 10 __ 11
|
13

Comment: use `unordered_map<list<int>>` instead.

Comment: With such small matrix I'd prefer `std::array<std::array<bool /*or size_t for weighted */, 4>, 4>`, i. e. the adjacency *matrix*. Nothing prevents you from mapping Node 9 to index 0, 10 to index 1, etc. In given case, you can do the mapping by simply subtracting 9...

Comment: I meant `unordered_map<int, list<int>>`.

Comment: @Aconcagua Thanks for your response. unordered map solved my purpose.